# How to remove spaces from a column in a list using Linq?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am passing a Json array as list to a MVC controller. How to remove spaces from a column in a list using linq? My json array is given below.

```
var Refresh = function () {
    var Product = [
       {
           ProductCode: 'P 1',
           ProductName: 'P1Name',
           ProductType: "T1",
           Amount: "2000"
       },
       {
           ProductCode: 'P4',
           ProductName: 'P4 Name',
           ProductType: "T4",
           Amount: "2000"
       },
       {
           ProductCode: 'P2',
           ProductName: 'P2Name',
           ProductType: "T2",
           Amount: "2000"
       }
     ]
```

In the above array remove space from ProductCode `'P 1'` to `'P1'` and from ProductName `'P4 Name'` to `'P4Name'`.

Comment: You should try something first

Comment: Maybe he's asking to see some variations. I don't see any reason to vote down beginner's questions if it is clearly written.

Comment: above functions is javascript no??

Answer (score 3):

```
jsonList  = jsonList.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)).Distinct().ToList()
```

Empty string and whitespace are like null. If it is not you can use IsNullOrEmpty, or s != null.

Comment: op wants remove space from column value  not remove field value

Comment: actually OP has given wrong requirement as per his code, he wants to remove space from column value and indicate from column, so up voting it

Comment: I want to remove space from column value

Comment: Thanks @sandip-patel

Answer (score 1):

Another Way by using `ForEach` in `LINQ`

```
products.ForEach(p=>{
p.Code=p.Code.Replace(" ","");
p.Name=P.Name.Replace(" ","")
})
```

Comment: Actually that list is <T> object. So is it possible to do dynamically finding all columns and replace space?

Comment: @Pradeep, To get fields list try this: `var Fields = Product[0].GetType().GetProperties().ToList();`. Note this code will cause exception if array is empty.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to iterate through all the columns and replace their values, try this code:

```
Product.ToList().ForEach(i => {
    i.GetType().GetProperties().ToList().ForEach( p =>{
        p.SetValue(i, p.GetValue(i).ToString().Replace(" ",String.Empty));});

    i.GetType().GetFields().ToList().ForEach( p =>{
        p.SetValue(i, p.GetValue(i).ToString().Replace(" ",String.Empty));});
});
```

*Note, if you have list of objects of anonymous type, this code will not work since anonymous classes have read-only properties which cannot be changed.*